# Echo can't use custom context in HTTPErrorHandler

Tags: go, go-echo

```golang
e.Use(func(h echo.HandlerFunc) echo.HandlerFunc {
  return func(c echo.Context) error {
    cc := c.(*CustomContext)
    return h(cc)
  }
})


e.HTTPErrorHandler = func(err error, c echo.Context) {
  cc := c.(*CustomContext)
}
```

I set custom HTTPErrorHandler and CustomContext.

I want to use CustomContext in HTTPErrorHandler.

```
c.Error(echo.NewHTTPError(http.StatusUnauthorized, "error"))
```

is work well.

but, panic `echo.Context is *echo.context, not *CustomContext` error when access not registered page.

Why occurred panic error when access not found page?

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do... but you can't replace the echo context with some arbitrary type. What is the end-goal you're trying to achieve? This feels a lot like an XY problem.

Comment: I just want to set error handler in custom context for make 404 error page.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you need a custom context. You can make a 404 page without that.

Comment: It also might be important to note that interfaces may be simplified, but not made more complex. Here is a mini example. In your case, you can set a `CustomContext` to a `echo.Context`, then, cast it back, but if it isn't originally a `CustomContext`, you can't "upgrade" it to one. https://play.golang.org/p/BnFquWSBsbk

Comment: custom context converting is work very well in other method. i just guess echo.NotFoundHandler work before custom context converting middleware work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate cause of the panic is that the error handler is being called with a "standard" context. To make your type assertion safe, use the two-value form:

```
e.HTTPErrorHandler = func(err error, c echo.Context) {
    cc, ok := c.(*CustomContext)
    if ok {
        // A CustomContext was received
    } else {
        // Something else, probably a standard context, was received
    }
}
```

But more generally speaking, what you're doing (using a custom context type) is probably a bad idea.  If you explain what you're trying to accomplish, there is probably a better, more robust way to solve it.

One obvious alternative would be to use standard Go contexts, as exposed through echo via `c.Request().Context()`.

Comment: oh, i found a good solution. thanks! i use custom context for access DB, Session, my function, etc easily. i dont think use custom context is bad way. and i cant find better solution.

Comment: A standard go `context` is the better way.